# can I use WF 4 in this situation or not?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, workflow-foundation-4

I am trying to figure out whether ms Workflow WF 4 is usable in the following scenario? Trying to create a web application in asp.net mvc 3.

There is a situation in an office where there are different roles. A form has to pass approval from different roles ( Projectmanager, Teamleader, Director).
So the Projectmanager creates a form , submits it for approval to the teamleader . The teamleader approves a notification and approves this form. Then after he approves and submits it , it will be going for approval from the director. If he does not approve he will send the form back to the Project manager.

Is this useful to implement this into a WF 4 in conjunction with asp.net mvc 3 or is this not advisable?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Selection of a new technology depends upon a lot of criteria. So if you want to decide to use workflow or not to address your business problem, create a small POC with your current requirement. Validate it, is this most suitable way? Do your team know this technology well? What is the learning curve required?

From my point of view your current requirement is suitable to use workflow 4.0. It is long running process and required frequent human intervention.

You can refer these links also..

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd851337

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee342461.aspx

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc709416

Comment: Not necessarily. The alternatives are hardly better and a lot less generic.

Comment: There is no need for WF4 for such simple app. Just because EF4 is cool doesn't mean its a good suit for the problem.

Answer (score 1):

I wanted to express some concern about WF4. It seems to me like you are describing a workflow from a birds point of view. The workflow being that a piece of information (the form) has to be approved by multiple parties, each with different responsibilities.

When you look at the problem from an MVC prospective you will find the following:

1. You have ASP.NET forms authentication with role based authentication.
2. You have multiple models - the piece of information (form as you called it) as well as multiple others - such as the `project manager`, `team leader`, and `director`. Further more a plethora of other joiner tables/entities in your Domain Model (Entity Framework 4/LINQ2SQL/NHibernate)...
3. Each person should have a different set of views they can access, based on their permissions, in order to interract with that data.
4. Behind each view you also have controllers taking care of the grunt work for reading/writing to your data source, as well as other logic.

While you can certainly create workflows to achieve some logic in your app - ultimately those workflows will be called from your controllers. Further more if the process of approval from each party is to click on an "approve" button or some other UI interaction - I don't think it makes sense to use WF4 to achieve this.

In my opinion WF4 is not well suited for UI interaction. It is really good when you want to create backend code that manipulates lots of data and/or orchestrates complex logic to achieve some task. However in the scenario you described you don't really have such kind of use.

Your approval process should at most set an "approved" record in the database containing the FormID, ApproverID, DateApproved, ApproverType and maybe some other info. (The approver ID being the Guid/uniqueidentifier of the user doing the approving).

The views displaying "pending approval" forms for both Team Leader and Directors should just query the forms table where a join on the approvals table yelds a null record (aka... an approval record doesn't exist) In any case - depending on your Domain Model and how the data is structured you really don't need much more than your controllers to achieve what you are looking for.